# Delphi XE2 64 bit ISAPI Access Violation

Tags: delphi, iis-7.5, delphi-xe2, isapi

Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit
IIS 7.5
Delphi XE2

i made a simple WebService/ISAPI DLL using delphi XE2.
this web service has a function that returns the sum of two numbers and made a simple client application to test this function.
When i compile it (along with the client) as a 32 bit application (in a virtual directory with a 32-bit enabled app pool), all works fine

when i compile it as a 64 bit DLL (the client is also compiled as a 64-bit aplication) i alws get an access violation error "class ERemotableException with message 'Access violation at address 0000000002199F33 in module 'MyWebService.dll'. Read of address 0000000000000000'."

i checked all IIS7.5 permissions i should do (the 32 bit ISAPI DLL works fine) and the problem kept appearing.

here is some quick test feed back:

if i used a TRemotable class descendant to pass data in a procedure --> no pb

however, writing a simple function that returns an integer causes the access violation.
i also tried to use native wndows data types such as Int64 without luck.

did some one had such a problem before? because frankly i am desperate.

Here is the code:

This is the webmodule interface

```
{ Invokable interface IMyDebugModule }

unit MyDebugModuleIntf;

interface

uses Soap.InvokeRegistry, System.Types, Soap.XSBuiltIns;

type

  { Invokable interfaces must derive from IInvokable }
  IMyDebugModule = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{02A5AD69-24E4-447B-8882-804DA687A0F2}']

    { Methods of Invokable interface must not use the default }
    { calling convention; stdcall is recommended }
    //function MyFunc():double;stdcall;
    function MyFunc():Int64;stdcall;
  end;

implementation

initialization
  { Invokable interfaces must be registered }
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(IMyDebugModule));

end.
```

and the implementaion

```
{ Invokable implementation File for TMyDebugModule which implements IMyDebugModule }

unit MyDebugModuleImpl;

interface

uses Soap.InvokeRegistry, System.Types, Soap.XSBuiltIns, MyDebugModuleIntf;

type

  { TMyDebugModule }
  TMyDebugModule = class(TInvokableClass, IMyDebugModule)
  public
    function MyFunc():Int64;stdcall;
  end;

implementation




{ TMyDebugModule }

function TMyDebugModule.MyFunc: Int64;
begin
  Result := 101;
end;

{ TMyDebugModule }


initialization
{ Invokable classes must be registered }
   InvRegistry.RegisterInvokableClass(TMyDebugModule);
end.
```

and here is the client app WSDl pascal file:

```
// ************************************************************************ //
// The types declared in this file were generated from data read from the
// WSDL File described below:
// WSDL     : C:\MyWorkingDir64\MyTests\WebServiceDebug\Client\IMyDebugModuleWSDL.xml
// Version  : 1.0
// (19/04/2013 09:46:52 - - $Rev: 37707 $)
// ************************************************************************ //

unit IMyDebugModuleWSDL;

interface

uses InvokeRegistry, SOAPHTTPClient, Types, XSBuiltIns;

type

  // ************************************************************************ //
  // The following types, referred to in the WSDL document are not being represented
  // in this file. They are either aliases[@] of other types represented or were referred
  // to but never[!] declared in the document. The types from the latter category
  // typically map to predefined/known XML or Embarcadero types; however, they could also 
  // indicate incorrect WSDL documents that failed to declare or import a schema type.
  // ************************************************************************ //
  // !:long            - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[]


  // ************************************************************************ //
  // Namespace : urn:MyDebugModuleIntf-IMyDebugModule
  // soapAction: urn:MyDebugModuleIntf-IMyDebugModule#MyFunc
  // transport : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http
  // style     : rpc
  // use       : encoded
  // binding   : IMyDebugModulebinding
  // service   : IMyDebugModuleservice
  // port      : IMyDebugModulePort
  // URL       : http://devserver2008/BahaaDebug/BahaaDebug.dll/soap/IMyDebugModule
  // ************************************************************************ //
  IMyDebugModule = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{64033E30-8D6E-F252-4E38-55502BF4E1A5}']
    function  MyFunc: Int64; stdcall;
  end;

function GetIMyDebugModule(UseWSDL: Boolean=System.False; Addr: string=''; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO = nil): IMyDebugModule;


implementation
  uses SysUtils;

function GetIMyDebugModule(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): IMyDebugModule;
const
  defWSDL = 'C:\MyWorkingDir64\MyTests\WebServiceDebug\Client\IMyDebugModuleWSDL.xml';
  defURL  = 'http://devserver2008/BahaaDebug/BahaaDebug.dll/soap/IMyDebugModule';
  defSvc  = 'IMyDebugModuleservice';
  defPrt  = 'IMyDebugModulePort';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
    if UseWSDL then
      Addr := defWSDL
    else
      Addr := defURL;
  end;
  if HTTPRIO = nil then
    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)
  else
    RIO := HTTPRIO;
  try
    Result := (RIO as IMyDebugModule);
    if UseWSDL then
    begin
      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;
    end else
      RIO.URL := Addr;
  finally
    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;


initialization
  { IMyDebugModule }
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(IMyDebugModule), 'urn:MyDebugModuleIntf-IMyDebugModule', '');
  InvRegistry.RegisterDefaultSOAPAction(TypeInfo(IMyDebugModule), 'urn:MyDebugModuleIntf-IMyDebugModule#MyFunc');

end.
```

and the test unit that called the function

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, IMyDebugModuleWSDL, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  w:IMyDebugModule;
  i:integer;
begin
  w := GetIMyDebugModule(True,'',nil);
  i := w.MyFunc;
  caption := IntToStr(i);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Can you show code. Both sides of the interop interface.

Comment: i edited the question to include the code. Thank You.

Comment: Do you have all Xe2 updates installed?

Comment: Frankly no. i know that i should, but from where i am it is hard to download large amount of data over the net (slow connection + quota limitations). I ll update an come back with an answer. Thank you for your time. and please forgive me for forgetting to mention that i am still on update 1 when i described my development environment.

Comment: Early XE2 had some serious COM bugs in the 64 bit compiler. You do need the updates to be clear of those. It looks like you are using COM here!

Comment: No really. No COM. it is just a simple example. A very basic function that returns an integer. Looks like it is not only about COM :) will update and recheck. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hmm. I can see lots of interfaces.

Comment: it is only the "IMyDebugModule" interface.

Comment: sorry for taking so long. i have waited to buy a Support Package and installed Delphi XE4. Problem is gone. I did not test with updated XE2. i jumped to a Delphi XE4 license directly. Thank you David for you help.